# LGA 2011 socket (i7-3930K) pin DDR2_CS_N[5] SSTL broken. Socket is toast?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i7

**EDIT: It seems that my 4am self, even with a quadruple check, managed to have an off-by-one error :) The pin is actually P18 which is listed as 'P18 DDR2_CS_N[5] SSTL O' I'm guessing this means it's toast... anyone want to confirm?**

LGA 2011 Socket (i7-3930K). Pins were bent in one area, managed to correct all pins except one. This one pin would not correct and ended up breaking off altogether (leaving only a tiny stub extruding from the socket, which will make no contact with the CPU).

I analyzed and cross-referenced (and double, triple, quadruple checked) the machine diagram and datasheet from Intel to find that the land number of the pin is N18. However, this land number is not listed under the tables provided. The closest section in the tables is the following excerpt:

> VCCD_23 H22 PWR
>   VCCD_23 H24 PWR
>   VCCD_23 N15 PWR
>   VCCD_23 N17 PWR
>   VCCD_23 N19 PWR
>   VCCD_23 N21 PWR
>   VCCD_23 N23 PWR
>   VCCD_23 V16 PWR
>   VCCD_23 V18 PWR
>   VCCD_23 V20 PWR
>   VCCD_23 V22 PWR
>   VCCD_23 V24 PWR

(taken from page 86, 'Sheet 31 of 45', of this document: [i7_LGA_2011_datasheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BNjpT3YyKjhJqM0PojfA4tV7sfWnfc2u))... had to upload to google drive; for some reason the Intel website link isn't working consistently...

To me, it seems that N18 isn't even used for anything. And additionally, even if it was, it would probably be used for powering `VCCD_23` (given that N17, N19, and N21 all are), which also shouldn't be a problem since there are many many more lands for powering `VCCD_23`.

Is this a reasonable assumption? Should I go ahead and replace the CPU and continue operating normally? Will this harm the CPU/socket? I am a little nervous that N18 is used for some super top secret, and important/vital,  feature and is therefore unlisted.

Comment: As it is an LGA ... how did you actually go about correcting anything? With the amount of time you have spent to do this it's likely that you're having a tight budget or similar. So you will either have to risk it and give it a try or replace the CPU.

Comment: This is one video I referenced (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fkioojsxX8&t=45s) Additionally, the reason for trying to fix it is that LGA 2011 x79 boards aren't as easy/cheap to find anymore, with all the new sockets out there. If I were to upgrade the motherboard,  I would also have to upgrade the cpu, and the RAM to DDR4. I would really like to not pay 200+ dollars for the 16gb of ram this system needs, and so I am seeing if this will fly fine with the broken pin :) If not, I may just have to eat that obscene RAM cost for now and upgrade.

Comment: Which specific board is this? Judging by the presence of DDR0 through DDR3 in the datasheet, these refer to either specific slots or channels - you might be able to sneak by by not populating the 3rd slot/channel (only using the DDR0, DDR1 and DDR3 slots/channels).

Comment: The board is TPower Biostar x79 (http://www.biostar-usa.com/app/en-us/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=567#overview). There are 4 slots for ram, and the document has 'DDR{0/1/2/3}_CS_N[5:4]' listed as 'Chip Select. Each signal selects one rank as the target of the
command and address.'... hmmm sounds important...